# How can I use androdx at api android level less than 28?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, androidx, mobile-development

everyone, i am a newbe in the Android development (java, android studio).
I want to create an app with minSDKversion 25. Am I correct in understanding that I can't use AndroidX for this and accordingly "implementations" as Firebase and similar required Android API 28 and higher?
And is it possible to combine in one project a version that supports com.android.support and androidx dependencies?

Comment: "Am I correct in understanding that I can't use AndroidX for this... required Android API 28 and higher?" -- most of the Jetpack (AndroidX) libraries work back to API Level 15. "is it possible to combine in one project a version that supports com.android.support and androidx dependencies?" -- it is not a good idea, largely because `com.android.support` libraries are very old and are no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

-> As Android moved towards MAD skills so its not possible to combine android x with simple android lib

-> you can set it minSdk 25  compileSdk 28 and target should be 28 in your gradle app level file

Comment: Thank You very much, i'll definitely try it ^^